# Jackson XML "Undeclared general entity" caused by custom entity

Tags: jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm deserializing a large XML file (not mine) and it contains custom entities defined as:

```
<!ENTITY math "mathematics">
```

and elements used this way:

```
<field>&math;</field>
```

When I try to deserialize it by:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
return xmlMapper.readValue(classloader.getResourceAsStream("file.xml"), MyClass.class);
```

I get this error:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Undeclared general entity "math"

I think it might be a security measure to prevent Xml External Entity injections.

1. Is there a way to mark these custom entities as valid? Like create an Enum for them or something?
2. If not, is there a flag to just parse these as Strings?

Update:
I was able to work around this problem by basically doing a find-replace on the text file. It's quite an ugly solution and if anyone has a better idea, I'm all ears. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it may be a little late, but just in case someone else is stuck on the same issue:

You have to set a custom XMLResolver as XMLInputFactory's property:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.ctc.wstx.api.WstxInputProperties;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLResolver;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;

var xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.getFactory().getXMLInputFactory().setProperty(
    WstxInputProperties.P_UNDECLARED_ENTITY_RESOLVER,
    new XMLResolver() {
        @Override
        public Object resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId, String baseUri, String ns) throws XMLStreamException {
            // replace the entity with a string of your choice, e.g.
            switch (ns) {
                case "nbsp": 
                    return " ";
                default: 
                    return "";
            }
            // some useful tool is org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils
            // e.g.
            // return StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4('&' + ns + ';'));
        }
    }
);

// then xmlMapper.readValue....
```